# Sort multidimensional array data into numerical order

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a snippet of code that looks like this:

```
foreach ($final_array as $index => $data) {
    echo $data[1];
}
```

What I want to do is sort $data[1] into numerical order. I've tried things like asort() and natsort(), but nothing worked. Any help would be HIGHLY appreciated.

This is how my array looks:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Awesomedude123
        [1] => 399,408
        [2] => September 16, 2012
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Username11
        [1] => 1,914,144
        [2] => September 16, 2012
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => EpicSurfer
        [1] => 1,031,427
        [2] => September 16, 2012
    )
)
```

Comment: And this is why you shouldn't store numbers as strings with commas in them.

Comment: Do a simple `explode(',',$data[1])` and do whatever you want with it. I would really like you to consider reading the PHP manual first and get familiar on everything that might be possible before asking questions on SO where you could have find the solution yourself in less than a minute.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for tricky array sorting:

```
function number_compare($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = str_replace( ',', '', $a[1] );
    $t2 = str_replace( ',', '', $b[1] );
    return $t1 - $t2;
}    
usort($array, 'number_compare');
```